# What features do you look for (or use most) in refactoring tools?

Tags: language-agnostic, refactoring

I'm familiar with the basics, such as "Extract Method." But that is about all that I use. What others are there? This can include refactoring tool features and also macros that you write yourself.

Answer (score 3):

From Resharper

- The safe Rename feature.
- Member/Variable highlighting.
- On-the-fly Error Detection
- Importing Namespaces

Also, a very nice Macro to use (this will also get you into creating your own)

[Visual Studio Macro: Collapse Solution Explorer](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/think-clients/visual-studio-macro-collapse-solution-explorer-18035)

> A macro that collapses all the tree
>   nodes in the solution explorer...

This is very usefull in larger solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I use IntelliJ IDEA, most frequently

- Rename (it can also rename getters/setters, and references in comments, literals and even non Java files like Hibernate mapping files)
- Introduce variable / constant / field / parameter
- Inline variable / constant / field
- Extract Method, of course (the mother of all refactorings)
- Change method signature (very useful)

And then there are a lot more which are needed less frequently, but when they are needed, they are needed *badly*:

- Extract interface / superclass / class
- Move method / class

Although Rename looks sort of trivial, it is still the most important of all. Finding good and better names for my program elements is a constant activity. Good names can make an enormous difference in the readability of a program.

OTOH the archetype of refactorings is Extract Method, because that is far more tricky to automate right. There can be lots of pitfalls, like possible name clash with a supertype method (or even worse: inadvertently overriding one), in/out parameters etc. So this has been a sort of threshold test for automated refactoring tools for long, although, I believe, by now the common ones tackle it well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ones @astander mentions, I use Convert Local Variable to Field (and vice versa) with some frequency.  And when I need it, Pull Up (that is, make a method on a subclass be a method on the superclass instead) is REALLY nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

In IDEA in addition to what Péter Török mentioned I use a lot of:

- Pull members up
- Push members down
- Safe delete

And some useful code generation (implement method, override method, generate constructor).